# Touch coordinates/location distorted

Tags: uiview, sprite-kit

Hi all I have a spritekit scene "Menu"
that I am loading a UIView as a subview (CGScratchViewController.xib)

```
-(void)addscratchView:(SKView*)view
    {
         CGRect viewFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width);

        //ScratchableView : UIView
        myScratchView = [[ScratchView alloc]initWithFrame:viewFrame ];
        self.name = @"menuScene";
        [self.view addSubview:myScratchView];

    }
```

ScratchableView class loads a layer that i can erase with my finger an overlay drawing revealing a drawing below

the code seems to be working however the touches are off and seem to be "scaled" somehow, meaning that if I draw in the top left corner the touch is in the correct place, but dragging the finger outward and the touch becomes more and more distorted
 - any thoughts on what to look for to correct this 
 (am a newbie making newbie mistakes)

Scratchableview.h

```
//  Created by Olivier Yiptong on 11-01-11.
```

//

```
#import "ScratchableView.h"


@implementation ScratchableView
@synthesize contentScale;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {

    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

        scratchable = [UIImage imageNamed:@"scratchable.jpg"].CGImage;
        width = CGImageGetWidth(scratchable);
        height = CGImageGetHeight(scratchable);
        self.opaque = NO;
        CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();

        CFMutableDataRef pixels = CFDataCreateMutable( NULL , width * height );
        alphaPixels = CGBitmapContextCreate( CFDataGetMutableBytePtr( pixels ) , width , height , 8 , width , colorspace , kCGImageAlphaNone );
        provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(pixels);


        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(alphaPixels, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);
        CGContextFillRect(alphaPixels, frame);

        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(alphaPixels, [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);
        CGContextSetLineWidth(alphaPixels, 20.0);
        CGContextSetLineCap(alphaPixels, kCGLineCapRound);

        CGImageRef mask = CGImageMaskCreate(width, height, 8, 8, width, provider, nil, NO);
        scratched = CGImageCreateWithMask(scratchable, mask);

        CGImageRelease(mask);
        CGColorSpaceRelease(colorspace);
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextDrawImage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() , [self bounds] , scratched);
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{


    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    if([[touch view] isKindOfClass:[UIImageView  class]]){
        CGPoint point= [touch locationInView:touch.view];
        NSLog(@"%f%f",point.x,point.y);

         location = point;
    }

    firstTouch = YES;
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event touchesForView:self] anyObject];

    if (firstTouch) {
        firstTouch = NO;
        previousLocation = [touch previousLocationInView:self];
    } else {
        location = [touch locationInView:self];
        previousLocation = [touch previousLocationInView:self];
    }

    // Render the stroke
    [self renderLineFromPoint:previousLocation toPoint:location];
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event touchesForView:self] anyObject];
    if (firstTouch) {
        firstTouch = NO;
        previousLocation = [touch previousLocationInView:self];

        [self renderLineFromPoint:previousLocation toPoint:location];
    }
}

- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
}

- (void) renderLineFromPoint:(CGPoint)start toPoint:(CGPoint)end {

    CGContextMoveToPoint(alphaPixels, start.x, start.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(alphaPixels, end.x, end.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(alphaPixels);
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    CGContextRelease(alphaPixels);
    CGImageRelease(scratchable);
    CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
}
```

and Menuscene

```
-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {

    self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
    skView.showsFPS = YES;
    skView.showsNodeCount = YES;

   // [self createButtons ];
    [self addscratchView:view]; //for testing


}

-(void)addscratchView:(SKView*)view
{
     CGRect viewFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width);

    myScratchView = [[ScratchView alloc]initWithFrame:viewFrame ];
    self.name = @"menuScene";
    [self.view addSubview:myScratchView];

}
```

I've tried to convert the coordinates...still not much luck (maybe its not the right thing to do anyways ..

```
    //convert between view coordinates and scene coordinates
    //coordinate system is not the same in a Sprite Kit scene as they are in a UIView
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
   CGPoint touchlocation = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
    spriteView = (Menu *) spriteView.scene.view;

    CGPoint positionInScene = [self convertPoint:touchlocation fromCoordinateSpace:spriteView.scene.view];
```

Video of the effect/distorted touches
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dMrcufcKpao

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are not layering your views the way you are thinking you are laying them in your head.

Right now you have it layered like this

Back of the screen
SKView
--SKScene
ScratchView

Now when this is happening, here is how your views are probably laid out size wise.

SKView->UIBuilder Default (600x600 I think)
--SKScene-> SceneBuilder Default (600x600)
ScratchView->ScreenSize

Your SKView will then resize to the screen size with AutoConstraints, but your scene will stay at 600x600 because you do not set the scaleMode to .ResizeFill,  so now you have 2 different coordinate systems, with scaling all off.

I think the best option for you right now is to just set your scaleMode to .ResizeFill (`skView.scaleMode = .ResizeFill`)  so that all your coordinates line up,  and as you learn more about what SpriteKit has to offer, you can refactor your code better to suit your needs.

Comment: what I did in the end was change @implementation GameViewController, removing -(void)viewdidload, replacing with - (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews, scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill; This is because at this moment when the system calls the viewDidLoad method, no view is appended in the calling hierarchy. Therefore the size and the orientation of the view cannot be adjusted (at least thats my understanding??)
this seemed to fix the problem. thanks Knight of dragon it put me on the path to the right solution!

Comment: kinda the same approach, but aspect fill may not work for you on various devices,  i would test on a 4s, 5~6s(only one needed), and iPad